# Can anyone tell me which set this LEGO plane is from?

Tags: set-identification, sets, set-database, set-numbering

[image]Im looking through my old LEGO sets and discovered this plane and I have no idea which set its from or the details. Could anyone help me out please?[image]

Answer (score 9):

Searching *Bricklink.com* for all sets that have *[Part # 30056 - Fence 4 x 4 x 2 Quarter Round Spindled with 2 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30056&in=S).*

[image]

We get the image of your plane, which is from *[Set #3451 - Sopwith Camel.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3451-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*

[image]

Looks like your model needs a serious dusting.